JAX-RS resource is not forwarding to JSP file
I'm having trouble creating a web service to redirect to a JSP file. I'm getting the following error when running the url of the created web service:
ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010023: Request HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /WSService/ws/showView ] was not original or a wrapper.

Below I detail the code I have:
The web.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <display-name>WSService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/showView/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>login.WSService</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>

This is the WSService class:
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@Path("/showView")
public class WSService {

    @GET
    @Path("/redirect")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public void redirect(@Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            String data = "someData";
            request.setAttribute("data", data);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("view/view.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

I placed the JSP file in the next path:
/src/main/webapp/view/view.jsp


The terms "forward" and "redirect" are not interchangeable. You might want to take a step back and research that area for the exact difference.

This doesn't look like the right way to do this. You'd typically send a redirect response. Something like:
@Path("/showView")
public class WSService {

    @GET
    @Path("/redirect")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response redirect(@Conect UriInfo uriInfo) {
        return Response.status(Status.MOVED_PERMANENTLY).location(uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path("/view/view.jsp")).build();
    }

}

In RESTEasy, and likely other implementations, the HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest are definitely wrapped.
